# Trying to export a working zip file from Eclipse but exported file when imported has no packages or build path

Tags: java, eclipse, build, path, export

I have a working program on my computer. When I try to export it using
[These export settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quSRg.png)

it gets bugged on reimport and the file structure is
[this file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMxYa.png)
It has no build path or packages and therefore does not run. Is there something wrong I am doing? Is it possible my settings are bad?

Comment: Before answering the question, make sure, what do you want to achieve? (a) Produce an executable jar? (b) Export the entire project folder as a zip file, which can be used to import the project on another machine using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

A .zip file is a collection of files and folders that are typically compressed for reducing storage space and improving portability. A Java project is exported to a .jar file and not a .zip file so the JVM can open the archive and execute the code.

From your question I see that you want to export your code to an executable archive, but the file extension is incorrectly given as .zip instead of .jar.

I would recommend you to learn more about how Java files are packaged into .jar file, entry point, manifest, and similar processes [here](https://www.albany.edu/faculty/jmower/geog/gog692/ImportExportJARFiles.htm)

Comment: We are forced to export as a zip file for the class I am in

Comment: You can't execute a zip file using JVM

Comment: Its not executing its importing the zip file back into eclipse and then executing it

Comment: Just open the project folder in Explorer/Finder and zip it using some compression tool

Answer (score 0):

In the original image, the files that control project definitions and the Java Build Path, `.project` and `.classpath` respectively, where not selected. You'll want to keep including the `.settings` folder.

Comment: Even with those two selected it makes no difference

Comment: `.classpath` is what stores the paths to your source folders, so that doesn't make sense. Do you have an updated image? Maybe less aggressively cropped when showing the reimported result?

Comment: Just updated it so you can see better the top is the original folder and the bottom is the imported version.

Comment: @MichaelStewart According to your screenshot you have imported it as subfolder into an existing project instead of a project of its own. Use _File > Import...: General > Existing Projects into Workspace_ and choosing _Selecting archive file: ..._